# Mac OS X Carbon: What is the difference between SelectWindow vs. ActivateWindow and what are the Cocoa equivalents

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

The title basically sums up my question.  I'd like to know what the difference between the Mac Carbon SelectWindow and ActivateWindow(..., TRUE) is.  I've found these in old source and wonder if they are interchangeable (or what their Cocoa equivalents might be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory...

SelectWindow was the response to clicking on a window. It brought the window to the front, activated it, and (usually) made it the first responder.  (I'm using Cocoa terminology here.)  It's sort of like `OrderFront`

> The SelectWindow function removes highlighting from the previously
>   active window, brings the specified window to the front, highlights
>   it, and generates the activate events to deactivate the previously
>   active window and activate the specified window. If the specified
>   window is already active, SelectWindow has no effect. Call
>   SelectWindow when the user presses the mouse button while the cursor
>   is in the content region of an inactive window.

Activate Window updated the window frame to indicate that the window was the first responder.

Comment: since I'm porting to Cocoa, I guess I'll just make them both makeKeyWindowAndOrderFront and hope it'll turn out to be pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Don't try a line-for-line port from Carbon, at least not for a significant program.  You'll make yourself miserable.  Are you working with PowerPlant or another Carbon framework?

Comment: I'm using a homegrown framework. We started the app in Carbon a few years ago, because it lent itself to easier porting from Windows, because I was new to MacOS and XCode, so back then I figured I didn't even want to add an unknown language (OBJC) into the mix too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to know a Cocoa equivalent, you just need to identify what you want to do. Many things from Carbon that required you to implement them are done for you by AppKit. Other paradigms of Carbon APIs just do not happen in Cocoa. They look similar, and had many similar hooks to common OS things, but they're very very different.

Comment: Problem is, these are base-classes for a multi platform library (MacOS and Windows) and over time it turned into something where functions did the equivalent of Windows in some way and I've long forgotten why there is a SelectWindow in one place (instead of ActivateWindow) and vice versa.  So, as far as there are equivalent behaviors, I now try to just do the same thing in Cocoa.

Comment: Makes sense. Sounds like it is just activating the window or "making it key" and "first responder"